# Where are sitecore logs on azure?

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore-azure

Sitecore 6.6 was deployed on azure using Sitecore Azure 3.0 tool. I'm looking for sitecore logs,because I need to see who changed particular item, but I can't find them. So I'm interested in AUDIT log lines.

I was looking in blob storage, but there are only containers: cacheclusterconfigs, publishtargets, sitecore-auto-deploy, wad-control-container, wad-iis-logfiles.

I was looking in table storage, using azure storage explorer, but there are only tables: WADDiagonsticInfrastructureTable, WADDirectoriesTable, WADLogsTable, WADPerformanceCountersTable, WADWindowsEventLogsTable.

Where are audit logs stored?

Answer (score 2):

Bartłomiej.

You can find Sitecore log entries in the WADLogsTable table into Azure Storage Service that Sitecore Azure module creates during deployment.

Please take a look at the following article for more details:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/400950

Best Wishes,
Oleg Burov

Answer (score 2):

With Sitecore Experience Platform 8.2, the location of the log files has been updated: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/911837

Logs can now be accessed via Application Insights.  Find the proper Application Insights object:

[image: App Insights Filtering]

Select the object, which will launch a new window:

[image: Select App Insights]

Open a new tab (query) and enter the following query exactly:

```
traces
| extend scinstancename=parsejson(customDimensions).InstanceName
| where timestamp > now(-1d)
| summarize count(), any(tostring(scinstancename)) by cloud_RoleInstance
| extend InstanceName=any_scinstancename
| extend CloudRole=cloud_RoleInstance
| project InstanceName, CloudRole
| order by InstanceName asc
```

Hit 'GO'.

Find the instance you wish to view the logs of, and take note of the CloudRole column:

[image: Find Cloud Role]

Lastly, run the following query in a new tab, swap out the 'CloudRole' with the role you found from the previous step:

```
traces
| where cloud_RoleInstance == 'REPLACE_THIS_ROLE'
| where timestamp > now(-14d)
| project timestamp, message
| sort by timestamp desc
```

The log file is displayed below:

[image]

Results may be exported to CSV if desired:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore logs, by default, are stored in a folder named "logs" under the folder specified in this setting in the web.config file:

```
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/data" />
```

By default, this value is "/data". In a typical non-Azure implementation, this value is usually an absolute path to the "Data" folder that is one level up from the Sitecore "Website" folder.

When using the Sitecore Azure module, this value is transformed to "**/App_Data**" during deployment. So you would find your logs under "**/App_Data/logs**" on your Azure instance.

If you don't want to access the logs via file system/remote desktop, you can also view them within the Sitecore desktop interface. Simply log in to the Sitecore desktop, then click the **Sitecore button -> Reporting Tools -> Log Viewer**. In the Log Viewer application, you will be able to open and view a log file from the Sitecore instance you are logged into.